# How is negation of a tautology a tautology?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I am reading the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1259006395) Elements of Discrete Mathematics by C L Liu. On the first chapter about Sets and Propositions, under the heading TAUTOLOGIES the author states

> It may be observed that the conjunction of a tautology is also a tautology. **The negation of a tautology is also a tautology.**

[Screen Grab from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbtmm.png)

How is this true? OR It is not true and just a mistake that needs to be corrected?

Comment: Thanks. Can you post that as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is wrong (it must be a typo...).

The negation of a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Definition_and_examples) is a formula that is Always FALSE, i.e. a [contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction#In_formal_logic).

---

*Note* added June 27.

I've browsed the Second Ed. (1985) of Liu's textbook and I've not found the wrong statement.